# Google Chrome defaulting to ftp instead of http for my site

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I have a website that I maintain.  I visit the site every now and then and type: "www.mysite.com" into the address bar of Chrome.

The issue is that Chrome converts that web address I typed into a a full FTP URL as "ftp://www.mysite.com" and prompts me for my ftp login/password.  The workaround is to manually re-type "http://www.mysite.com" into the address bar.

I suspect it's doing this because at one point a long time ago, I legitimately used Chrome as an ftp client to upload/download some files to the site.

Now I just want to make it forget that it ever did this and just default to http.

Suggestions?

Comment: Clear the browser's history?

Comment: @margineau - Yep.  That works. Although I was hoping it wouldn't come down to it. Chrome has a neat feature where you can selectively delete from history, but that didn't work when I deleted all history references to my site.  I had to delete all "from the beginning of time".  Thanks!